# Adding a new column based on values

Tags: sas

I have the following sample data:

```
data weight_club;
  input IdNumber 1-4 Name $ 6-24 Team $ StartWeight EndWeight;
  Loss = StartWeight - EndWeight;
  datalines;
1023 David Shaw         red    189 165
1049 Amelia Serrano     yellow 145 124
1219 Alan Nance         purple   210 192
1246 Ravi Sinha         yellow 194 177
1078 Ashley McKnight    green    127 118
;
```

What I would like to do now is the following:

- Create two lists with colours (fe, list1 = "red" and "yellow" and list2 = "purple" and "green")
- Classify the records according to whether or not they are in list1 and list2 and add a new column.

So the pseudo code is like this:

```
'Set new category called class

If item is in list1 then class = 1
Else if item is in list2 then class = 2
Else class = 3
```

Any thoughts on how I can do this most effciently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pseudocode is almost exactly it.

```
If item is in ('red' 'yellow') then class = 1;
Else if item is in ('purple' 'green') then class = 2;
Else class = 3;
```

This is really a lookup, so their are many other methods. One I usually recommend as well is Proc format, though in a simplistic case like this I'm not sure of any gains.

```
Proc format;
    Value $ colour_cat
    'red', 'yellow' = 1
     'purple', 'green' = 2
      Other = 3;
Run;
```

And then in a data/SQL either of the following can be used.

```
*actual conversion;
Category = put(colour, $colour_cat.);

 * change display only;
 Format colour $colour_cat.;
```